# How to handle large scale js+jquery projects using well written, Object-Oriented JavaScript and jQuery code?

Tags: learning, object-oriented, javascript, jquery

I love the whole user experience/interface thing and put a lot of jQuery and JavaScript (pure JavaScript for HTML5 stuff, like canvas, file API, etc). The problem I face now is that my codes are growing large, 3-4 files per project with each file around 1000 lines of code, and maintaining and extending them is becoming a headache.

I know that Object-Orientated JavaScript coding can solve a lot of my problems. I know the basic concepts of Object-Orientated Programming, have done a decent amount of it in C++, Java and Python in school and college projects. I want to read some good examples large scale OO programming in JavaScript (and jQuery), or if possible, some book specifically on writing big OO programs in JavaScript.

EDIT1: Checked out backbone.js, guess thats what i needed, will be sure once i use it in my next project, thanks Raynos, also, my question should have been about handling large js projects, and not what it is, sry

Comment: Using [custom events](http://www.reynoldsftw.com/2009/04/custom-events-in-jquery-open-doors-to-complex-behaviors/) is a good way to tackle complexity.

Comment: Try using organisation libraries like curl/require for modularisation and Backbone/spine/sammy/knockout for MVX style structure. Also I'd recommend you read node.js projects as they have good examples of OO js

Comment: I'd also recommend you only use `Object.create` and [traits](http://traitsjs.org/) for your OO. This along with AMD modules should keep your code tight and structured

Comment: Have a look at [JavaScript MVC](http://javascriptmvc.com/)

Comment: Use C# instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out backbone.js so far its one of the best solutions (along with javascript mvc) to give some order into the caos/beauty of large scale javascript applications. If you think its overkill I would recommend separating your files in some kind of structure, for instance a file with all of the event bindings, another file for all of the ajax calls another one for anything that edits the html.... if you think about it you are kind of already trying to make a type of mvc structure so check out those tools first and see what they have to offer.

Comment: doing that already, working on my firm's portfolio and it has many different js stuff going on. Hadn't used backbone.js when i started working on it so started making separate files for each piece of work. It has eased the development process a lot, and I can always combine and minify them at the time of production. By the way, from what I have read of backbone.js, its the perfect lightweight addition for at least medium scale apps

Answer (score 2):

[ExtJS](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/) is an highly refined, completely extensible library of Javascript UI components that shows the power of OO programming in Javascript.  You could also look at [the jQuery source](http://jquery.com), or the [Yahoo! UI library](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/3/).

Answer (score 1):

Google for **Scalable JavaScript Architecture**. You'll find a lot of resources for what you want. Some of them are:

1. [Nicholas from Yahoo](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/theater/video.php?v=zakas-architecture)
2. [Nettuts+](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/scalable-javascript-application-architecture/)

Also you can follow JavaScript design patterns in books like **Pro JavaScript Design Patterns** from Apress.

I also recommend subscribing to the feed of some good sites like:

1. [DailyJS](http://dailyjs.com)
2. [JavaScript Kit](http://www.javascriptkit.com)